# Is it possible to separate two signals in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have asignal and I would like to decompose it into two..

this is the [datasetTot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ik3gu0maaqvtmaf/datasetTot.dat?dl=0) of both signals

```
ListPlot[datasetTot, PlotStyle -> {Black, Black}]
```

[image]

I know that this signal is a sum of two signals whose shape is like this

[image]

My question is: can I get the green and red signals separately from the original data `datasetTot`?

**update**

the green and red signals are

```
green={-2 Tanh[1 - x] + Tanh[x], Tanh[x] + 2 Tanh[1 + x]}
red={3/2 (Tanh[2 x] - Tanh[2 (1 + x)]), 3/2 (Tanh[2 - 2 x] + Tanh[2 x])}
```

Comment: Can you assume that you know the green and red signals ahead of time? (Data/definitions for them are not provided in your example).  If so, it seems like you could `NMinimize` a least-squares expression for the black signal as a linear combination of the red and green signals (with two real parameters describing the coefficients of the red and green contributions)

Comment: Do you know equations that red and green curves are described with?

Comment: I only know how the profiles of the two signals would be, as I showed in green and red which is synthesized data.

Comment: Please provide the equations for the two profiles. Afterwards, you could use ``NonlinearModelFit`` to get the two coefficients (as Joshua already proposed).

Comment: kindly, see update for the green and red profiles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not very elegent approach ... You fit the linear combination of both components to obtain the coefficients (which in your case seem to be 1). Then, you separate the signal by subtracting one of the components (I used the green one).

```
data = (* ... *);

green = {-2 Tanh[1 - x] + Tanh[x], Tanh[x] + 2 Tanh[1 + x]};
red = {3/2 (Tanh[2 x] - Tanh[2 (1 + x)]), 3/2 (Tanh[2 - 2 x] + Tanh[2 x])};

fit = MapThread[
   NonlinearModelFit[#1, g #2 + r #3, {g, r}, x] &, {data, green, 
    red}];

Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[{fit[[1]][x], fit[[2]][x]}, {x, -4, 4}]]

Through[fit["BestFitParameters"]]

(* {{g -> 1., r -> 1.}, {g -> 1., r -> 1.}} *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
separated = 
  Table[{#[[1]], #[[2]] - g green[[i]], g green[[i]]} /. 
       fit[[i]]["BestFitParameters"] /. x -> #[[1]] & /@ 
    data[[i]], {i, 2}];

Show[{
  ListPlot[separated[[All, All, {1, 3}]], PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Green],
  ListPlot[separated[[All, All, {1, 2}]], PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]